# Disable newline on assignment

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, formatter

I just started using IntelliJ and my first impression is "what the hell is this ugly-ass formatting?"

For whatever reason, the IntelliJ formatter adds a newline after the equals operator, so I am stuck with this:

```kotlin
    fun setTo(
        vec: Vec2F) {
        x =
            vec.x
        y =
            vec.y
    }
```

I want it to look like this:

```kotlin
    fun setTo(vec: Vec2F) {
        x = vec.x
        y = vec.y
    }
```

But I can't find the setting for it in the IntelliJ settings. Can someone tell me where it is?

Comment: ktlint was suggested to me shortly. But I haven't tried it yet. https://ktlint.github.io/

Comment: It was doing something like that to me after opening braces and I tried everything I could think of and asking on here about it, and finally gave up and reinstalled. At least that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

That's bizarre behaviour, which I've never seen…<sup>*</sup>  It should behave rather better than that, especially when first installed!

The exact setting is probably `Preferences` → `Editor` → `Code Style` → `Kotlin` → `Wrapping and Braces` → `Assignment statement`.

But you might want to try resetting the whole scheme (at the top of that pane), either by reselecting a scheme or clicking on `Set from…` → `Kotlin style guide`.

---

<sup>(* I rarely use an automatic formatter, though, because I haven't found one that formats as well as I do :-)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! There are a couple of things I should mention that could be relevant: This was a 2019 something version of IntelliJ that was updated. Secondly, this is a Kotlin JS project which had a `kotlin.code.style=official` line in `gradle.properties` by default. I did a reset on the formatting settings and the code style was not the same at all as in my question post. I'll do a reinstall of IntelliJ.